# Binary heap application

Tags: algorithm, search, binary-search-tree

I just finished an exercise about the notion of Binary Heap. However, I don't have the solution to this problem, but I found an answer in this exercise. Could someone verify that the solution I got is correct ?

Thanks in advance !

[image]

Here is the answer I got :
x F G M K T S Z U Q

Comment: To understand the answer you need to know two things. First, how to insert the new value into the existing tree. Second, how to flatten the resulting tree into an array.

Comment: @user3386109 I got the answer FGMKTSZU. I just wanted to know if it is the correct solution or not :)

Comment: How exactly did you get that answer? :) [Edit] the question and explain the method that you used to get the answer.

Comment: @user3386109 Ok, first of all I put the node G as a children of the node Q since in a binary heap we add nodes from left to right. Then I compare first the node G with his parent Q since G is less that Q, we can swap both. We do the same process, we compare G with his new parent K. K> G then we can swap both again. And finally A<G so G stay at the same place. To find the sequence we read the binary heap from left to right. That’s how i got my answer. Does it seem correct for you ? :)

Comment: Yes, that is the correct way to find the answer, and the answer that you got is correct.

Comment: You can post that below as an answer to your own question, @Student123. It is correct.

Answer (score 0):

The given binary heap is Max Heap , where Heap Size is 8

```
            F
         /     \
      K          M
    /   \      /   \
   Q     T    S     Z
  /
 U
```

To insert letter G , we follow MAX-HEAP-INSERT algorithm.

**Step 1 -** Increase heap size by one , and put -∞ in the end so now our binary heap looks like this..

```
            F
         /     \
      K          M
    /   \      /   \
   Q     T    S     Z
  / \
 U   -∞
```

**Step 2 -** Now increase the size of -∞ to G using HEAP INCREASE KEY ALGORITHM

```
            F
         /     \
      K          M
    /   \      /   \
   Q     T    S     Z
  / \
 U   G
```

G may violate Heap condition, goes up to the root and exchange G with parent until you find valid heap.

**exchange G with Q**

```
            F
         /     \
      K          M
    /   \      /   \
   G     T    S     Z
  / \
 U   Q
```

**Exchange G with K**

```
            F
         /     \
      G          M
    /   \      /   \
   K     T    S     Z
  / \
 U   Q
```

The resulted Heap is valid Heap no more exchange needed.

Let write this heap in the form of array -

x F G M K T S Z U Q